# Finding standard deviation, standard error and summary of all columns of sheet and storing the info in new table in R-language

Tags: r, dataframe, function, na, standard-deviation

```
calculate_stats <- function(x) { 
non_missing_values <- na.omit(x)
if (length(non_missing_values) >= 1) {
sd_val <- sd(non_missing_values, na.rm = TRUE)
se_val <- sd_val / sqrt(length(non_missing_values))
} else {
  sd_val <- NA
  se_val <- NA
}
return(c(sd_val, se_val))
}
result <- t(sapply(df, calculate_stats))
print(result)
```

This code has resulted into this warning message:
Warning message:
In var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) :
NAs introduced by coercion
I am really clueless, please help me out.

I want to know the cause of my error and would love to learn and try again.

Comment: Run `str(df)` to see if your data has columns other than numeric.

Comment: Thank you that helped, now I can get back to coding.

Answer (score 0):

Rui's comment should help!

My 2 cents: I assume you want to learn R, but if you are just interested in the SD and SE, you could also run:

```
# uncomment next line if psych is not installed
# install.packages("psych")
library(psych)
describe(df)
```

This will give you different stats, including sd and se. Furthermore, it also shows which variables are not numeric (the ones with the asterisk *); these are converted to numeric before calculating the stats. If you just want to show sd and se, simply filter the columns afterwards.